# FactoryGirl Name "can't be blank" VS "already taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to run some tests on a model "Click".

```
# models/click_spec.rb
describe Click do
    it "should have a valid constructor" do
        FactoryGirl.create(:click).should be_valid
    end
end
```

The objective is that the model uses two tables that have the **same** country. I don't want to use a sequence for the country (as I found for Emails).
But it raise this error:

```
Validation failed: Name has already been taken, Slug has already been taken
```

The problem is that it seems that it create twice the country [name:"United States", slug:"us"]

Here's the factories used.

```
# factories/countries.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :country do
        name "United States"
        slug "us"
    end
end

# factories/offers.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :offer do
        association :country, factory: :country
        # Other columns
    end
end

# factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        association :country, factory: :country
        # Other columns
    end
end

# factories/clicks.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :click do
        association :offer, factory: :offer
        association :user, factory: :user
        # Other columns
    end
end
```

and the model of Country:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :slug,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    validates :slug,
    length: { is: 2 }

end
```

I've tried to change the association strategy to something like this:

```
association :country, factory: :country, strategy: :build
```

But it raise this error:

```
Validation failed: Country can't be blank
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the shared code,

when you call `FactoryGirl.create(:click)`,

it will go to execute `factory :click` where it finds `association :offer, factory: :offer`
which in turn calls `factory: :offer` where you create a country with `name "United States"` and `slug "us"` for the first time.

Again, in `factory :click`, it finds  `association :user, factory: :user` which in turn calls `factory: :user` where you create a **country again with the same `name "United States"` and `slug "us"`** for the second time.

> **Issue #1: Validation failed: Name has already been taken, Slug has already been taken**

The above error is because of the **uniqueness constraint on `Country` model for `name` and `slug`**.

> **Issue #2: Validation failed: Country can't be blank**

When you do `association :country, factory: :country, strategy: :build` then `strategy: :build` only creates an instance of Country, it does create a record in database.

The `Country can't be blank` error is because you didn't create a country record in the database for `user` and `offer`. And you must be having a validation `presence: true` in these two models for `country` OR schema level check of `not null`.

Comment: The thing is that the association :user should use the Country that was created by the association :offer. Something like the `find_or_initialize_by` of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Refer to `factory_girl` documentation at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations Its not find_or_initialize_by BUT create

Comment: Yes, I've already read it, but didn't help to solve my issue. I was wondering if there's an equivalent for `find_or_initialize_by` in FactoryGirl that could fix my issue (I used `create` in the my question).

Comment: Now, your question is getting changed. Your original question was `FactoryGirl Name “can't be blank” VS “already taken”` and my answer explains why. Post another question for it as chaining or modifying original question via comment is not a good practice.

Comment: Done. There's a uniqueness constraint on Country, but my main issue is that it create twice the same record of Country when I call once `FactoryGirl.create(:click)`

Comment: Post another question means a totally new question for  `find_or_initialize_by in FactoryGirl` and NOT to modify the current question. My answer explains why you were getting error `FactoryGirl Name “can't be blank” VS “already taken”`.

Comment: Also, for your reference FactoryGirl does not offer find_or_initialize_by feature. See which all methods you can use here:  https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories

Comment: Okay thanks, however it should be something that I'm missing, it must be common use case. Btw, I just cleaned up things. The new question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874292/find-or-initialize-by-in-factorygirl

Comment: So What happens to this question? If it resolved `FactoryGirl Name “can't be blank” VS “already taken”` issue then accept it.

Comment: I don't think that it's the solution for this question. As I already mentioned in my question that the model country have 'uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }' constraint. Since there's two errors “can't be blank” and “already taken” in the both cases, the issue is still unsolved.

Comment: @simox See my updated answer. This should resolve both your questions.