# find_or_initialize_by in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I was wondering if there's an equivalent for `find_or_initialize_by` in FactoryGirl that solve teh following issue:

The objective is that the model uses two tables that have the **same** country. I don't want to use a sequence for the country (as I found for Emails).

There's a uniqueness constraint on Country, but my main issue is that it create twice the same record of Country when I call once FactoryGirl.create(:click)

Thus, the Validation fail in the test.

Rspec:

```
# models/click_spec.rb
describe Click do
    it "should have a valid constructor" do
        FactoryGirl.create(:click).should be_valid
    end
end
```

Factories:

```
# factories/countries.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :country do
        name "United States"
        slug "us"
    end
end

# factories/offers.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :offer do
        association :country, factory: :country
        # Other columns
    end
end

# factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        association :country, factory: :country
        # Other columns
    end
end

# factories/clicks.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :click do
        association :offer, factory: :offer
        association :user, factory: :user
        # Other columns
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :slug,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    validates :slug,
    length: { is: 2 }

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to make this work by using `initialize_with`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :country do
    name "United States"
    slug "us"
    initialize_with { Country.find_or_create_by_name(name) }
  end
end
```

This will always use the same country. You may want to nest the factory to allow other factories to use different names:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :country do
    initialize_with { Country.find_or_create_by_name(name) }
    factory :united_states do
      name "United States"
      slug "us"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues, also with the `Country` model of my application. Here's what I did.

To ensure FactoryBot's `build` and `create` still behaves as it should, we should only override the logic of `to_create`, by doing:

```rb
factory :country do
  to_create do |instance|
    instance.id = Country.create_with(name: instance.name).find_or_create_by(slug: instance.slug).id
    instance.reload
  end

  name { "United States" }
  slug { "us" }
end
```

Query explained:

```rb
Country
.create_with(name: instance.name) # if not found, create with this `name` (and `slug` defined below)
.find_or_create_by(slug: instance.slug) # find by primary key `slug'
```

This ensures `build` maintains it's default behavior of "building/initializing the object" and does not perform any database read or write so it's always fast. Only logic of `create` is overridden to fetch an existing record if exists, instead of attempting to always create a new record.

Originally posted on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55235861/3956879.

*Check out my [article](https://dev.to/jooeycheng/factorybot-findorcreateby-3h8k) explaining this.*